# AlertView pop up twice for single Button

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I have two sample button, and with each of them, two different `alertView` should pop up separately. The first one works well, but hitting second one, don't know why the two `alertView` pop out together, one after one.

Here is the code :

```
- (IBAction)AlertViewButtonTwo:(id)sender
{
UIAlertView *myAlertOne = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"AlertView" message:@"AlertViewOne" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"GoToYahoo", @"GoToYoutube", @"GoToFacebook", nil];
myAlertOne.tag = 1;

[myAlertOne show];
}

- (IBAction)AlertViewButtonThree:(id)sender
{
UIAlertView *myAlertTwo = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"AlertView" message:@"AlertViewTwo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"GoToDailyStar", @"GoToProthomAlo", @"GoToNewAgeBD", nil];
myAlertTwo.tag = 2;

[myAlertTwo show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (alertView.tag == 1)
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // this is the cancel button
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com/"]];
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 2)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/"]];
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 3)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/"]];
    }
}
else if (alertView.tag == 2)
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // this is the cancel button
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.thedailystar.net/"]];
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 2)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.prothom-alo.com/"]];
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 3)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.newagebd.com/"]];
    }
}
}
```

I new here in iOS. If any one told me the missing point, that will be much appreciable.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How did you create the buttons and set the targets?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get you...Wain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your buttons probably has multiple target/action pairs connected to it so it is calling both methods when you expect it to only call one. Check the connections in the XIB / storyboard and remove any that shouldn't be there (probably as a result of copying or a misplaced drag).

Comment: Thanks man, i was just copy the "AlertViewButtonThree" button from "AlertViewButtonTwo" button at the time of creating in storyboard, while that was already had an action in "class.h" file. I delete the previous button ("AlertViewButtonThree"), created a new one & now it works fine. Thanks for you comment. @Wain